# DateTime Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to pass a null value for a DateTime variable in C#. The value should be stored in the database as null.

I've tried using Datetime.Minvalue, but that stores a default value. It has to be a null in database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 10):

Use `DateTime?` as in

```
DateTime? foo = null;
```

That makes a **[nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(VS.80).aspx)** `DateTime`:

> A nullable type can represent the
>   normal range of values for its
>   underlying value type, **plus an
>   additional null value**.

then when writing the value out, you can use the value like this:

```
if(foo == null)
{
   // Handle the null case
} 
else 
{
   // Handle the non-null case
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the nullable type answer, but when you go to write it to the database, you still need to test for null and convert it to DBNull.Value.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DateTime?` values type. It can have `null` values but otherwise it's completely the same as `DateTime`

Comment: ah you are few seconds too late.

Comment: @Sung: Fastest gun in the west syndrome :-/

Comment: @Daniel: When I refreshed the page, timestamp said, 2 seconds ago, but I already saw 2 answers

Comment: Mine was second, I saw a yellow line about new answer the moment I've clicked a button